# How to order posts, that have already been filtered by custom taxonomy, by their category names?

Tags: wp-query, loop, query-posts, order

My question is not a duplicate, because in my case posts have already been sorted by custom taxonomy term. The question is how to order posts by their category name AFTER they have been sorted by custom taxonomy.

This is for online scientific journal. I have posts attached to categories. Those posts are also attached to custom taxonomy called `journals`.

First I need to retrieve all the posts that are attached to specific custom taxonomy term. Then I need to list the posts ordering them by their category names.

This is the actual page I'm working on. Please, visit to get a better idea: http://journal.fledu.uz/en/journal/1-15-2017/

I'm thinking of prefixing all the category names so that I can order them by their names like this:

`01 Some category name`

`02 Another category name`

`03 Category name`

`04 And so on`

Here's my query:

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var('term'), 

get_query_var('taxonomy') );
$term_date = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'journal_date', true);

$journals = get_terms('journals');


$jurloop = new WP_Query(
    array( 
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order'   => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'journals',
              'field' => 'id',
              'terms' => $term, // Where term_id of Term 1 is "1".
              'include_children' => true
            )
          )
        )
    );
```

The the loop:

```
<?php if ($jurloop->have_posts()) :  ?>
   <?php while ( $jurloop->have_posts() ) : $jurloop->the_post(); ?>
            my stuff
   <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I order the posts by the names of the categories that they are attached to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ordering Posts List By Taxonomy Terms?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209870/ordering-posts-list-by-taxonomy-terms)

Comment: My question is not a duplicate, because in my case posts have already been sorted by custom taxonomy term. The question is how to order posts by their category name AFTER they have been sorted by custom taxonomy.

Comment: Ideally there is no *after*, you must do it all in the same query, the linked question is applicable in this case for understanding how to accomplish that.